# Behavior of $\tan(\frac{1}{n}) - (\frac{1}{n})$ when $n\to +\infty$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to see whether certain series converges or not.

In my textbook solutions it says:

> Notice that $\tan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) - (\frac{1}{n})$ behaves as $\frac{1}{3n^3}$

I have absolutely no idea why this is the case. I suppose $\tan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ behave the same but I don't see how is that relevant

I'd appreciate an explanation (if not, hints are welcome too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From asymptotics relations:
$$\tan(t)\,\,\sim\,\, t$$
when $t\to 0$.
In this case, $\frac{1}{n}\to 0$ when $n\to+\infty$. So:
$$\tan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\,\,\sim\,\,\frac{1}{n}$$
Using only asympotitics relations is not sufficent. We must use Taylor-Maclaurin series for $\tan(t)$:
$$\tan(t)=t+\frac{1}{3}t^3+o(t^3),\,\,\, t \to 0$$

We have done:
$$\tan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{3n^3}+
o\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)=\frac{1}{3n^3}+
o\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\,\,\,\, n\to +\infty$$